# i can't install spring boot extension pack on vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions

i can't install Spring boot extension pack on vscode

```
[2022-06-13 21:05:14.065] [renderer1] [error] ["Extract: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\\Users\\valdi\\.vscode\\extensions\\.88390b88-fba4-4bc6-bd78-70ebb64b5614\\language-server\\META-INF\\third-party-open-source-licenses\\bsd 3-clause \"new\" or \"revised\" license (bsd-3-clause) - apl-v10.html'","    at F.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:213215)","    at async F.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:210606)","    at async $.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:217251)","    at async $.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:218192)"]
```

[2022-06-13 21:05:14.139] [renderer1] [error] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\valdi.vscode\extensions.88390b88-fba4-4bc6-bd78-70ebb64b5614\language-server\META-INF\third-party-open-source-licenses\bsd 3-clause "new" or "revised" license (bsd-3-clause) - apl-v10.html': Extract: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\valdi.vscode\extensions.88390b88-fba4-4bc6-bd78-70ebb64b5614\language-server\META-INF\third-party-open-source-licenses\bsd 3-clause "new" or "revised" license (bsd-3-clause) - apl-v10.html'
at F.extractAtLocation (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:213215)
at async F.extractUserExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:210606)
at async $.extract (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:217251)
at async $.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:218192)
[2022-06-13 21:08:28.035] [renderer1] [error] EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\valdi\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs.c97e77e0-4d74-49c2-b210-890ee18d1883' -> 'c:\Users\valdi\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs\pivotal.vscode-spring-boot-1.34.0': Download: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\valdi\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs.c97e77e0-4d74-49c2-b210-890ee18d1883' -> 'c:\Users\valdi\AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs\pivotal.vscode-spring-boot-1.34.0'
at $.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:219042)
at async $.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:217660)

Comment: Read [THIS](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug that should be reported directly to the extension creator. It appears that the following is the same issue https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/784

Comment: It is indeed, I solved with the VSIX file share on the link

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue and did the following to resolve it:

- Uninstall the old extension and also deleted it from .vscode\extensions\ folder
- In VSCode go to Extensions => Details => Releases and check for .vsix file installtion. Navigate to the download page (https://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html)
- Download the newer version of plugin (v 1.35.0.xxxx)
- Install it by running the command in terminal:
  code --install-extension /download/folder/plugin.visx
- Restart VS Code
  Hope it helps!